# What is 'vector<type[n]>' in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have encountered

> `vector<long[8]> a(n);`

recently but i don't know what is that ?

Comment: A vector of 8 element long arrays.

Comment: So it's the same as vector< vector<long>(8,n) > a right ?

Comment: Since that doesn't compile, no. More like a container of std::array<long,8>

Comment: @MiracleDistortion no, even if this code would actually compile, a vector is not an array.

Answer (score 4):

It means a vector whose element type is `long[8]`. However, for technical reasons, `std::vector<T>` cannot have an array type for `T` with the standard allocator because `p->~T()` is not defined when `T` is an array type. You would have to do something like `std::vector<std::array<long, 8>>` instead.